How to trigger bootstrap toast ? other then button type="button", or fetch()
Is there a simple, other solution to trigger my boostrap toast which doesn't involve a button?
Maybe like :
button onclick ="trigger my bootstrap toast the easy way"

without the need of fetch or a button type="button"?
I think I have overlooked a simple way to implement it.
My site code looks like this currently:
<form>
  <button=type"submit" name="need the name for my json key" value="need you also for my json"

This submits to my PHP background app, to save my value to JSON strings in a file.
Is there any simpler way to implement the call to trigger bootstrap toast?
The PHP background side is not the problem, for that I just want to POST my values to my PHP.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/toasts/#usage or https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/toasts/#live-example didn't help? How exactly do you trigger a toast using fetch?

So, you want the button to submit the form AND also not result in a navigation (which a form submit does) - sounds like you want two conflicting results from the one action.

@brombeer Thats my problem my JS knowleage is not so good that i can implement fetch over javascript ,  and no the examples dont work in my case they all needs to work with fetch or button type="button" change to button type"submit" will never trigger the toast.

@JaromandaX Yes i want the button to submit the form, or any other simple way to give the form to my PHP background. To Navigate / stay on the same side is ok. So just want : do my Post request and popup my toast to the user. why conflicting where can i read about what you mean sorry but i donst know much about JS. thx

or any other simple way to give the form to my PHP background except fetch(), i.e. the ONLY other way - if you want to POST to the server while not navigating, use fetch() or XMLHttpRequest - there is no third option

@JaromandaX means i can never trigger a Toast message and make a POST call at the same Time ? Pls why ? What I am missing, want to read about it what are the key words (conditions) ? Why are button onclick for some feature possible? thx a lot you are real helping me in my learning curve. Yes and want to read about it but dont get the entry point of understanding. thx

Of course you can make a POST "call" - your title says you don't want to though, because you don't want to use fetch ... so use XMLHttpRequest - that'll fit the question

Do you perhaps want to click on a button or some sort or clickable element, within then form, without submitting the form, to open a bootstrap toast?

If so, <button type="button"/>, by itself does not submit the form, even it is inside the form, unless you trigger an event of the button (click, blur if you fancy, etc) then execute a method that will do fetch, xmlhttprequest, ajax, axios whatever term that you know, then return response based on the result of that xmlhttprequest

thx also a lot i got your point you, are right i wanted it without fetch just html post. but my js learning is on the beginning. now i think want to implement the fetch version from @ADyson because button="button" dont trigger the html submit. thx again

It sounds like you want to submit your form data asynchronously using JavaScript and then show a toast message when the async request is complete.
Toast messages can be triggered via JavaScript, as per the bootstrap documentation - there is no direct dependency on, or requirement to use, a button.
This code will listen for a form submit event, prevent the default postback behaviour, then send an async POST request via fetch() which submits the form data to the server, and finally show the toast message when the POST request completes:
HTML:
<form id="frm1">
  Enter your data: <input type="text" name="field1" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit form</button>
</form>

<div class="toast-container position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3">
  <div id="liveToast" class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
    <div class="toast-header">
      <img src="..." class="rounded me-2" alt="...">
      <strong class="me-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
      <small>Test</small>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
      Form submitted
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

JavaScript:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const frm = document.getElementById("frm1");
  const toastLiveExample = document.getElementById("liveToast");

  const toastBootstrap = bootstrap.Toast.getOrCreateInstance(toastLiveExample);
  frm.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch(
      "https://www.example.com/submit.php", 
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: new FormData(frm)
      }
    )
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      toastBootstrap.show();
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
    });
  });
});

Live demo (with fake sink for the async request): https://jsfiddle.net/utazbhp2/3/

Thanks @ADyson you made my Day and understood my question as it is. Perfect, sorry seen you post late.

@al-nabaproject no problem. Remember to mark the answer accepted if it was useful

but pls one more expl., take me the whole day. How would I do a <button name="show up" and value="show up" show up over fetch. By html post is no prob. thx

@al-nabaproject buttons aren't serialised as part of the form data, because those are the rules when the button  didn't directly cause the request to the server. Why do you need to do that? Could you put the value into a hidden  field in the form instead, or something like that?
